# Java directory structure on github

Tags: java, git, github

My `bin` directory is currently being untracked; however, I would like that to be part of the repo as it contains the binary file to execute the program. On the other hand, the `build` directory is being tracked, which I do not want. How can I add the `bin` directory and remove the `build` directory?

[image]

Comment: Is there a `.gitgnore` file in your bin folder?

Comment: Take a look at [this document](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)

Comment: No, there isn't a `.gitignore` in the bin folder

Comment: @goodcow are hidden files shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I add the bin directory and remove the build directory?

First part:

```
$ echo build/ > .gitignore
$ git commit .gitignore -m"Add .gitignore"
```

This will ensure that `build` changes won't be tracked from now on.

Second part:

```
$ git rm -r --cached build
$ git commit -m"Remove build/ from tree"
```

This will remove `build` from the *index*, but not the working directory.

Third part:

```
$ git commit bin -m"Added bin"
```

Although you really should NOT do that; rather, you should be able to build `bin` from your project.

Comment: When I try to commit `bin`, it says that everything is up to date.

Comment: If it isn't committed already, make sure there is at least one file in it. Git won't add empty folders by default.

Comment: @GerardRyan good spotting; I am so used to git I don't even think about this kind of stuff anymore ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the structure of your project is like this (and is in a folder called `MyProject`):

```
|- MyProject
  |-bin
  |-build
```

Then to stop tracking `build`, you'll want to add a line to a file called `.gitignore` in `MyProject`. To add the `bin` folder, you can simply do from the `MyProject` folder:

```
git add bin
```

^^ assuming there's currently at least one file in `bin`. Once added, you can commit as normal.

As fge has pointed out, think a while before adding the `bin` folder. If the binary file within it can be created from the source code, then someone who clones your repository can do that themselves. Committing binary files is not usually what we want to do, because if they change regularly, then they will cause the size of the repository to grow quickly, among other things.